# I get two errors specified below when I upload this HTML file to Markup Validation Service

Tags: html, eclipse, xhtml

When I upload the below code to Markup validation service, I get errors about these two lines

```
<img src="hghg.png" height="123" alt="hello it's me" width="123"/>

<a href="https://www.uber.com/"> This will be a link</a>
```

This is the first error: **document type does not allow element "img" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag**

This is the second error: **document type does not allow element "a" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag**

below is the whole code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> No title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> the header</h1>

<p> The first paragraph </p>

<img src="hghg.png" height="123" alt="hello it's me" width="123"/>
<a href="https://www.uber.com/"> This will be a link</a>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>type</td>
  
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
  
  </tr>
  </table>
   
 <h4> another header</h4>
<ul>
  <li> first element</li>
  <li>second element</li>

</ul>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Strict, like HTML 4.01 Strict does not allow inline elements as the direct child of `<body>` elements.

Comment: What should I change in my codec? @Alohci

Comment: Wrap the `<img>` and `<a>` elements in block-level element like a `<p>` or a `<div>`. Or switch to a modern DOCTYPE. HTML5, in both its HTML and XML syntaxes, does not have this restriction.